# App or program to simulate a gear driven machine

Tags: windows, gratis, android, cad

I want to design a machine that uses gears, cams, etc. I am looking for a free Android app or Windows program that can simulate the design in motion. If the design is successful I want to build a physical machine from the digital design. If possible I'd like to incorporate some clockwork features such as a pendulum, governors, etc.